# I have this block of PHP which updates a table. I'm getting no error from the $errorMessage but doesn't update in my MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to edit a field which is prefilled with information from the database and form. I'm not getting any error from the $result and really wondering how to fix this. Thanks !

```
$sql = "UPDATE team SET position = '$position', team_name = '$team_name', game_played = '$game_played', q_won = '$q_won', q_lost = '$q_lost', points = '$points' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        $errorMessage = "Invalid query:" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using, and how is `$conn` defined? There are multiple ways of interacting with databases and it isn't clear which you are using, so one possible answer is that you are missing a call to `->execute()`.

Comment: Your query is wide open to mysql injection! Use prepared statements.

Comment: We can't possibly debug this without knowing anything about the database and the connection to it, but as @MarkusZeller said, it is really important to read about SQL Injection and prepared statements, especially if you are writing any sort of production code.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE team SET position = " .$position. ", team_name = " .$team_name. ", game_played = " .$game_played. ", q_won = " .$q_won. ", q_lost = " .$q_lost. ", points = " .$points. " WHERE id = " .$id. ";
```